# How to define good typings for this reduce function in Typescript

Tags: typescript, types

I have this function that is supposed to go through a locale object with type Record<string, string | object> so a object in this format:

```js
locale = {
    login:{
        loginMessage: "Please login"
    },
    register:{
        registerMessage: "please login"
    }
    etc.

}
```

that is the following function.It should go through the locale object and return the value of the key (string) that was given e.g "login.loginMessage".

i'm new to Typescript and types in general and for the love of god i can't seem to figure out how to tell typescript that the accumulator value is an object but the output is a string

```
const getKey = (key, locale): string =>
     
      key.split(".").reduce((localeObject, item) => {
        if (localeObject) {
          return localeObject[item];
        }
      }, locale);
```

this gives me the following error

```js
S2769: No overload matches this call.   Overload 1 of 3, '(callbackfn: (previousValue: string, currentValue: string, currentIndex: number, array: string[]) => string, initialValue: string): string', gave the following error.     Argument of type '(localeObject: Record<string, string | object>, item: string) => string | object' is not assignable to parameter of type '(previousValue: string, currentValue: string, currentIndex: number, array: string[]) => string'.       Types of parameters 'localeObject' and 'previousValue' are incompatible.         Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Record<string, string | object>'.  
 
Overload 2 of 3, '(callbackfn: (previousValue: Record<string, string | object>, currentValue: string, currentIndex: number, array: string[]) => Record<string, string | object>, initialValue: Record<...>): Record<...>', gave the following error.     Argument of type '(localeObject: Record<string, string | object>, item: string) => string | object' is not assignable to parameter of type '(previousValue: Record<string, string | object>, currentValue: string, currentIndex: number, array: string[]) => Record<string, string | object>'.       Type 'string | object' is not assignable to type 'Record<string, string | object>'.         

Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Record<string, string | object>'.
```

anyone willing to explain me how i can type this correctly?

Comment: Your example don't even compile

Comment: my bad this is a class method so this function doesn't work on its own. I will change it

Comment: this should work @captain-yossarian

Comment: What type do you expect in `key` and `locale`?

Comment: for key a string and for locale a Record<string, string | object>. I'm not sure if the locale type, is the correct type for the object that i show in the first example

Comment: It is hard to answer your question. You are shadowing `localeObject` variable in your `reduce`. What do you expect from reduce? Reduce shoul always return a value. In your case you returning value in `if` branch. I think you should read the docs https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const getKey = (key: string, locale: object): string | never => {
    const result = key.split('.').reduce<object | string>((o, k, i, a) => {
        if (typeof o === 'object' && o !== null && k in o) return o[k as keyof typeof o];
        else throw new Error(`Key path: ${a.slice(0, i + 1).join('.')} is not valid!`);
    }, locale);
    if (typeof result !== 'string') throw new Error(`Key path: ${key} is not valid!`)
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Awesome! I'll have to do my homework to completely understand how this works but thanks a lot